# How to create a descriptor matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, feature-descriptor

How do I create a descriptor in OpenCV that can be used with one of the DescriptorMatchers in OpenCV, in the following manner.

```
cv::BFMatcher matcher( cv::NORM_L2, false );
std::vector< cv::DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );
```

I already have the following descriptor class. How do I convert or create a new matrix that can be used with a DescriptorMatcher. Preferably BFMatcher.

```
class Descriptor
{
    public:
    float lxi, lyi; // Location of descriptor
    vector<double> feature;

    Descriptor()
    {
    }

    Descriptor(float x, float y, vector<double> const& f)
    {
         lxi = x;
         lyi = y;
         feature = f;
    }
};
```

Comment: opencv's descriptors are 1d float(SIFT/SURF) or uchar(ORB;BRIEF,etc) Mat's. so neither your Descriptor class, nor your vector<double> will work

Comment: I could drop my Descriptor class. Is there a way I can create a fresh descriptor matrix through my code? I could not find any info about the structure or form of the matrix.

Comment: no idea how you create your (custom ?) descriptors, but you could just create a Mat and push_back() values (just like with a vector)

Comment: I push the 128 features in feature and the x,y of the keypoint for the 128 features in each descriptor, which again gets pushed into an array of other descriptors.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this question, there is no documentation on how to create a custom descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

I just visit here when looking for the answers about the same question.
But soon I found the answer is so simple, all you need is to make a Mat.

For example , below is a some SIFT-LIKE descriptor.

```
cv::Mat descriptors_1(nQueries, dimemsion, CV_32F,(void*)pQueries);
cv::Mat descriptors_2(m_nDataSets, dimemsion, CV_32F,(void*)m_pData);

cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< cv::DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );
```