# How to create a custom descriptor for use with FlannBasedMatcher in opencv?

Tags: opencv, mat, flann

I have been using the `FlannBasedMatcher` in opencv and would like to create custom descriptors that describe, for example, the average colour etc of seperate images held in two arrays and match them using `FlannBasedMatcher`, is there a way to do this?

Also is it possible to match multiple descriptors at once (i.e. average colour, brightness, contrast) and match them all at the same time? I have already seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506500/how-to-create-a-descriptor-matrix-in-opencv#comment38270618_22506500). Thanks

Comment: Where u able to achieve this?